# Gradle - Add single file to JAR

Tags: file, jar, include, task, gradle

I have the file "license.txt" in the root directory of my project. In the jar-task, I want to add this file to the (root folder of the) JAR file.

I tried

```
jar {
  from '.' include 'license.txt'
}
```

but this *replaces* the other content (.class files) instead of *adding* a file.
And I do not want to add the license.txt to the resources folder, because I do not want to change my project structure just because of the build tool.

Who can help? Thank you!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To add a single file, you can simply do:

```
jar {
    from "license.txt"
}
```

Your solution should also work if you scoped your `include` to your `from` by enclosing it in curly braces.

Comment: Short and perfect answer. Thank you!

Comment: Can you give an example of scoping an include? I want to add certain dirs to a jar. When I use: from "${projectDir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF" then it only uses that dir, but I want to add this dir...

Comment: `from` is additive. It doesn't override anything.

Comment: [In my case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65645773/how-to-merge-client-and-server-builds-into-one-jar-with-gradle) those the files I want to add are generated and it seems that `jar` tries to add those files too early. Any idea how I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to add multiple files, you can do:

```
jar{
    from{
        ["aaa.txt","bbb.txt"]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would add multiple files to output jar as under:

```
jar {
    // Update jar name according to Ascertia conventions
    /**
     * archiveFileName
     * The archive name. If the name has not been explicitly set, the pattern for the name is:
     * [archiveBaseName]-[archiveAppendix]-[archiveVersion]-[archiveClassifier].[archiveExtension]
     */
    archiveFileName = 'database_postgresql.jar'
    from(['build/classes/java/main','mappings/postgresql'])
}
```

All contents in below directories will be added:

- build/classes/java
- /main/mappings/postgresql