# How to merge client and server builds into one jar with gradle?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle, jar

I have a project with the following structure:

```
web-client/     # Angular Client
  build/
  build.gradle  

server/         # Spring Boot Application
  build/
  build.gradle  

build.gradle    # The "parent" project. Works on web-client and server
```

The `parent` is supposed to copy the compiled web-application into `server/build/classes/static` such that it will be copied to `/BOOT-INF/classes/` of the final `jar` where it will be served by the Spring Boot server.

Everything is working so far except the last part. Those files are nor copied into the final `jar` and I think it's because it got already build at the time where the copying task is executed.

This is the script which I am currently using:

```kotlin
task buildWebApp {
    outputs.dir('mobile-client/build')
    dependsOn ':mobile-client:buildWebApp'
}

task copyWebApp {
    doFirst {
        copy {
            from 'mobile-client/build'
            into 'server/build/classes/static'
        }
    }
    dependsOn tasks.buildWebApp
}

# assemble.dependsOn copyWebApp
build.dependsOn copyWebApp
```

How can I make sure that those files from `mobile-client/build` end up in the final jar of `server`?

Answer (score 0):

Cannot guarantee its current functionality, but this I used in one of my projects a few years ago. I did use separate gradle submodule for building Frontend and then separate module for Backend where I included Frontend as a JAR:

```
root gradle project -> frontend
                    -> backend
```

#### Frontend build.gradle (builds frontend JAR with /static/**)

```
apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"
apply plugin: 'java'

node {
  version = '8.9.3'
  download = true
}

def webResources = "$buildDir/web-resources/main"

sourceSets {
  main {
    output.dir(webResources, builtBy: 'buildWeb')
  }
}

task webInstall(type: NpmTask) {
  args = ['install']
}

task buildWeb(type: NpmTask) {
  dependsOn webInstall
  args = ['run', 'build']
}

build.dependsOn buildWeb
```

#### Backend build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin'
apply plugin: 'idea'

dependencies {
  compile project(':frontend')
}
```